# Redirect URL with htaccess and regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess

How do I redirect:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/entrar-na-sua-conta.html?redirecionar=/f%C3%B3rum-perguntas-e-respostas/conversation/read.html?id=25
```

To:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/f%C3%B3rum-perguntas-e-respostas/conversation/read.html?id=25
```

Using `.htaccess` and `regex`?

I'm trying:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /entrar-na-sua-conta.html?redirecionar=/([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.portal-gestao.com/%1? [L,R=302]
```

And:

```
RewriteRule ^entrar-na-sua-conta.html?redirecionar=/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**?** is a special char in regex, so you need to escape it in the cond's pattern to match **?** literally :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /entrar-na-sua-conta.html\?redirecionar=/([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.portal-gestao.com/%1? [L,R=302]
```